# Any way to get <tr> to float for a responsive table layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I was curious if there was any way to get cell 4 to float next to cell 3?

I do not want to consider non-tabled solutions(please don't suggest, as I know how to do them).  I am just curious if the requested can be done verbatim.

Thanks to any HTML/CSS guru's who can offer any input.

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    max-width:500px;
}
td{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Desired Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to reset `<tr>` display as well.

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    max-width:500px;
}
tr {
    display:inline;
    font-size:0;/* kind of erase white-space */
}
td{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:1rem/* reset font-size*/;
      /* show me*/ box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Be aware that you might have strange bugs using this on old IE versions.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope  IE5x,6 did teach a lot to handle css and funny, unexpected behaviors, Ie7 was a mistake, to me those 2 are dead and won't get the mediaquerie in a responsive context anyhow. thi is why i really have no worries about them ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus this looks super promising.  Do you have any idea on the browser support of your solution?

Comment: @TimRamsey IE8 and later , firefox 1.0 and later, chrome, opera, ... actually any browser that undersrtand display:table(css2.1)  will do

Comment: @GCyrillus The font-size:0 did not work in Safari.  I did substitute the font size reset with word-spacing:-2em; which appears to work. Any ideas why this would not work in Safari?

Comment: @TimRamsey , it doesn't entirely works the same cross browser because the table was not reset , tr inline breaks part of the layout but not entirely ( table's width is still inherited to set 50% to td's when tr stands in between). each browsers plays it its own way. You could float the td instead inline-block.  can you try this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqdwQo

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is actually a non-tabled layout, you are just using table elements for it.

To make a table layout look like that, put two cells in each row:

```css
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not verbatim...The point was to control the layout with CSS and not structurally as the width of the td should control how many cell are on each line.

Comment: @TimRamsey: You can't do that with a table layout, so if you want that you have to use a non-table layout. If you do that with table elements, the default settings for them only get in the way.

Comment: The selected answer above shows how this can be done in all modern browsers that I care about.  Thanks for your input though...

Comment: @TimRamsey: No, it *can not* be done using a table layout. The other answer only shows how to do it with a non-table layout using table elements.